# HttpWebRequest GetResponse() not returning anything

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, getresponse

I have written a code to call a website which returns some data. I have used `HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()` method. When I hit the url in browser,  it returns data. However in my C# code, sometimes it returns data, sometimes it do not return anything.

The request is not throwing any error such as time-out or access denied. It returns nothing.
If I use debuggers in code, it returns data.

Code is as below;

```
HttpWebRequest clnt = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(restURL);
var resp = clnt.GetResponse();
if ((resp.ContentLength > 0))
{
    using (System.IO.StreamReader str = new System.IO.StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        if (str != null)
        {
            string response = str.ReadToEnd();
            str.Close();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me if I am missing anything.

Comment: You're missing a `using` statement for one thing - you should make sure you *always* dispose of the web response, even if there's no content. You haven't said what happens in the failure cases - does the request actually complete, but there's no content, or does it just time out? Also note that your nullity check is pointless - you've just called the constructor, so `str` can never be null.

Comment: If you don't do anything special with HttpWebRequest you could use WebClient:

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string response =  client.DownloadString(restUrl);
            }

Comment: The request is not throwing any error such as time-out or access denied. It returns nothing. If I use debuggers in code, it returns data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried giving the Method and Content type?

```
clnt.Method = "POST";
clnt.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

It will come like this :

```
HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        httpWReq.Method = "POST";
        httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();

        string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return responseString;
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I am geeting an error as The remote server returned an error: (411) Length Required.

Comment: Well..That must be becuase you have to POST . When you make a POST HttpWebRequest, you must specify the length of the data you are sending. If you need the codes please specify it.

Comment: When you're using HttpWebRequest and POST method, you have to set a content (or a body if you prefer) via the RequestStream.

Comment: Not sure what was the cause. After using GET it is now returning data.